$A^n$ can be written as a linear combination of $I,A, \dots, A^{n-1}$
Show that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $A^n$ can be written as a linear combination of the matrices $I, A, A^2, \dots, A^{n-1}$.
Here's my attempt. Since $A$ is $n \times n$, $A$ has a minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$. Now, the minimal polynomial always divides the characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)$. Explicitly write $p_A(x)$ as
$$p_A(x) = x^n+ \alpha_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots +\alpha_1x+\alpha_0$$
As $m_A(x) \mid p_A(x)$, we have
$$p_A(x) = m_A(x)g(x) \tag{$\star$}$$
for some other polynomial $g(x)$ over the associated field. Now, by definition $m_A(A)=0$, which means $P_A(A)=0$. Explicitly writing this, this means
$$p_A(A) = A^n+ \alpha_{n-1}A^{n-1}+ \dots +\alpha_1A+\alpha_0 =0$$
$$\iff A^n = -\alpha_{n-1}A^{n-1}- \dots -\alpha_1A-\alpha_0$$
giving the result. I'm having doubts about my solution because it feels almost immediate once you know

every matrix has a minimal polynomial
the minimal polynomial always divides the characteristic polynomial

Of course, intuition is always relative, but this problem appeared on a qualifying exam so it feels too good to be true.

"the characteristic polynomial always divides the minimal polynomial": no, it's vice versa. But you are right the required result is a trivial consequence of the Cayley Hamilton Theorem.

This is correct, and yes, the result is basically immediate. The proof, however, requires two important facts, so it could just be testing your knowledge of those facts and your ability to apply them.

@ancientmathematician Ah, I must have swapped them in my head. I have edited the post!

I'd just say it follows from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. You don't need to mention the minimal polynomial here. In fact, the reason why the minimal polynomial divides $p_A$ is because $p_A(A)=0$.

I sort of agree with @Mark, although I suppose it is possible to prove the CH Thm by proving that $m_A\mid p_A$ by calculating each!

@ancientmathematician Interesting. Is there really such a proof? Because as I know, $m_A$ is usually defined as the unique monic generator of the ideal ${f\in F[x]: f(A)=0}$. So not sure how to calculate it for a general matrix. (unlike $p_A$ which has an explicit formula $\det(xI-A)$)

@Mark I think that it follows from the Rational Canonical Form Theorem. Clearly the last invariant factor is $m_A$ and the product of the invariant factors is $p_A$. We can find the invariant factors algorithmically by the Smith Normal Form algorithm.

As Mark says in the comments, you don't need to discuss the minimal polynomial. This is an immediate consequence of Cayley-Hamilton already, since the characteristic polynomial has degree $n$.
More interestingly, it is possible to give an independent proof, without Cayley-Hamilton or even any determinants. Let $m_A$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$, which a priori (without CH) only has degree at most $n^2$. It suffices to show that $\deg m_A \le n$. Writing $V$ for the underlying vector space, the action of $A$ gives $V$ the structure of a $K[t]/m_A(t)$-module, and since $m_A(t)$ is the minimal polynomial this action is faithful. So it suffices to prove the following:

Theorem: A faithful module $V$ over a $K$-algebra of the form $K[t]/f(t)$, where $f(t) \in K[t]$ has degree $d$, has dimension $\ge d$.

Proof. Consider the irreducible factorization $f(t) = \prod f_i(t)^{e_i}$ over $K[t]$. By the Chinese remainder theorem $V$ decomposes as a direct sum $\bigoplus_i V_i$ of modules over the primary quotients $K[t]/f_i(t)^{e_i}$, which are faithful modules over $K[t]/f_i(t)^{e_i}$. This means we can find $v_i \in V_i$ such that $f_i(t)^{e_i-1} v_i \neq 0$. The annihilator
$$\text{Ann}(v_i) = \{ p(t) \in K[t]/f_i(t)^{e_i} : p(t) = 0 \}$$
must be an ideal of the form $(f_i(t)^k)$, since these are the only ideals, but by construction $e_i \ge k$, so $\text{Ann}(v_i) = 0$, meaning the $K[t]/f_i(t)^{e_i}$-module generated by $v_i$ must in fact be free. This gives $\dim V_i \ge e_i \deg f_i$ and hence $\dim V \ge \deg f$ as desired. In fact by construction the vector $v = \sum v_i$ has zero annihilator with respect to the action of $K[t]/f(t)$, so generates a free $K[t]/f(t)$-submodule of $V$. $\Box$

This argument may seem complicated at first glance but it is really only a slight variation of the familiar idea that if a finite abelian group has elements of orders $a, b$ then it has an element of order $\text{lcm}(a, b)$. We don't need the full strength of the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID.
For another nice proof see Lemma 2.1 of Skip Garibaldi's The determinant and the characteristic polynomial are not ad hoc constructions, which uses this fact (that $\deg m_A \le n$) to construct the characteristic polynomial without determinants.
