Index of Nilpotency of Square Matrices
If $A\in C^{n\times n}$ is nilpotent, the degree of nilpotency is less than $n$. How do I prove this?

This is about as hard as proving that the minimal polynomial of an arbitrary matrix has degree $\le n$, for which see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4949907/an-can-be-written-as-a-linear-combination-of-i-a-dots-an-1/4950053#4950053

By Cayley-Hamilton, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is of degree $\le n$. If $A$ is nilpotent, this polynomial is a power of $X$. So...

@QiaochuYuan I think one possible approach to the general case involves showing that the minimal polynomial of a matrix occurs as the minimal annihilator of some element.  But in this case, since the monic divisors of $\lambda^m$ form a chain, that's trivial to show -- much easier than showing it in the general case.

@Daniel: the general case essentially reduces to this case via the Chinese remainder theorem (see the answer I linked to), I really don't think they're that different.

What do you mean by the degree of nilpotency? Is it the minimal $k$ such that $A^k=0$?
